# Data binding not available in other function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to send a base64 encoded string to my server but the data binding I use is "" in the function to send it.

This is the code:

```js
processFile: function(event) {
      var rawFile = event.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(rawFile);
      reader.onload = function() {
        this.file = reader.result.split(',')[1];
      };
    },
```

So this.file contains the base64 string but when I access it in another function it's returning ""

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can use `ES6` like this:  `reader.onload = () => {
            this.file = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
processFile: function(event) {
      var rawFile = event.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(rawFile);
      reader.onload = function() {
        this.file = reader.result.split(',')[1];
      }.bind(this);
    },
```

or

```
processFile: function(event) {
      var rawFile = event.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(rawFile);
      var vm = this;
      reader.onload = function() {
        vm.file = reader.result.split(',')[1];
      };
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.
Could you explain why I have to instantiate "this"?

Comment: Unfortunately documentation is going away, which is why you were not allowed to link that. These days I have been marking these questions as a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: In my opinion one half of the vuejs questions is about scoping and one half about ajax and of course often they intersect.